# " ... cannot be used as a JSX component." warning

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

When I prepare a component like the one below, I get the warning in the picture. It doesn't give any warning if I create it with if instead of switch-case. Why does it give this warning when I use switch-case? How should I write the switch case so it does not give a warning?

```js
import React from "react"
import { Text } from "react-native"


const AppHeader = () => {

    const TextOne = () => (
        <Text>AAA</Text>
    )

    const TextTwo = () => (
        <Text>BBB</Text>
    )

    const TextComp = ({ text }: { text: string }) => {
        switch (text) {
            case "A":
                return <TextOne />
            case "B":
                return <TextTwo />
        }
        
        // if (text == "A") {
        //     return <TextOne />
        // } else {
        //     return <TextTwo />
        // }
    }

    return (
        <TextComp text={"A"} />
    )
}

export default AppHeader
```

[image]

Comment: Your switch statement has no default case so your component can potentially return `undefined` if an unexpected value is passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add default case with `null` in the switch-case
The error is because it returns `undefined` if text is not both "A" and "B", and it does not match type.